# How to make shifts in tensors (images) without having to make loops?

Tags: python, image-processing, pytorch, shift, torchvision

I want to perform displacements on tensors (set of images), for example using torch.roll or some other method. But each displacement I am going to apply to each tensor is different (I would have another tensor with the displacements). Is there any efficient way to be able to do it "all at once" without having to loop through each of the images?

for example I have the following simple tensor, which would correspond to two images

```
torch.tensor([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]).view(2,2,2)

tensor([[[1, 2],
         [3, 4]],

        [[5, 6],
         [7, 8]]])
```

And I need to apply a shift of 1px in x-axis to the first one and in y-axis to the second one.

```
tensor([[[2, 1],
         [4, 3]],

        [[7, 8],
         [5, 6]]])
```

Comment: Please clarify your question:

In the question _title_, the phrase "tensors (images)" implies that images is synonymous with tensors, i.e. each tensor is an image.

But in the body, you refer to a tensor as a "set of images". Presumably you mean a "stack of images"? Rather than a set?

The question seems to be saying you want to move all the images at once, but by different displacements. i.e. one image may move in the x direction and one in the y direction. Is that right?

Comment: Exactly as you explain, I want to move all the images at the same time, but with different displacements.

Comment: I can't think of a way to move each image by a different displacement, at the same time. Instead, I would recommend a loop, handling each image in turn, using torch.roll or similar.

Comment: I agree with @Eureka, i doubt there's a good way to do this all at once. At least not one that would take more processing than just applying `torch.roll` in a loop and concatenating the results. If you really wanted to you could use advanced indexing but im guessing it would take longer than the for loop to generate the appropriate indices.

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on the comments I think a for loop is likely the best way to do this

```py
import torch
data = torch.tensor([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]).view(2, 2, 2)

# define shift amount in y-axis and x-axis for each element
shifts = [(0, 1), (1, 0)]

# shift each image separately and concatenate them
data_shifted = []
for d, s in zip(data, shifts):
    data_shifted.append(torch.roll(d, s, dims=(0, 1)))
result = torch.stack(data_shifted, dim=0)

print(result)
```

which results in

```
tensor([[[2, 1],
         [4, 3]],

        [[7, 8],
         [5, 6]]])
```

The loop could be replaced with a one-line comprehension if you prefer

```
result = torch.stack([torch.roll(d, s, dims=(0, 1)) for d, s in zip(data, shifts)], dim=0)
```

All of this is autograd compatible just FYI

Comment: I have seen that it can be done with Kornia  https://kornia-tutorials.readthedocs.io/en/latest/rotate_affine.html

Comment: Using an affine transform seems to be overkill for just a shift. `torch.roll` should be more efficient assuming of course its implemented well in pytorch.

Comment: When you have hundreds of thousands or millions of images the use of the "for" loop is very inefficient. That's why I try to do the transformations in batches of images. Furthermore, in this case, in addition to applying the shift, I am interested in applying rotations.